# Why is this function in R placing a back slash in front of a decimal point?

Tags: r

I have the following function which is supposed to output a string of text, but appears to be adding in a backslash before the decimal point of a number:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
    center <- mean(x)
    cat("Mean = ",center)
}
```

Test it out with some numbers:

```
library(testthat)

x <-c(1,2,3,7)

    expect_that(
        myfunction(x),
        prints_text("Mean = 3.25"))

Error: `x` does not match "Mean = 3.25".
Actual value: "Mean =  3\.25"
```

How can I correct the function so that it prints the correct ("Mean = 3.25") output?

Comment: `prints_text` expects a regular expression. Note that `.` is a special character in a regular expression.

Comment: And note that `sep=" "` is default for `cat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit:

Scrap that, this works:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
  center <- mean(x)
  cat("Mean =",center)
}

expect_that(
  myfunction(c(1,2,3,7)),
  prints_text("Mean = 3.25", fixed=TRUE))
```

i.e. removing the space in `cat()` **and** adding `fixed = TRUE` because otherwise *any* result that has the number `3` followed by anything followed by `25` will pass the test.

## original but probably wrong answer:

This is because `testthat::prints_text` expects a regular expression. Add the argument `fixed = TRUE` (and `\.` escapes a literal point in regex)

i.e.

```
 prints_text("Mean = 3.25"),  fixed = TRUE)
```

## Final edit:

Since this seems to cause confusion:

This:

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
  center <- mean(x)
  cat("Mean =","3925")
}
```

Passes **this** test (!):

```
library(testthat)
expect_that(
  myfunction(c(1,2,3,7)),
  prints_text("Mean = 3.25"))
```

But **does not** pass this test:

```
library(testthat)    
expect_that(
  myfunction(c(1,2,3,7)),
  prints_text("Mean = 3.25", fixed=TRUE))
```

Comment: Is there any way to fix the problem without adjusting the expect_that code?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong but edited my answer. I'd suggest fixing `myfunction` because now it puts two spaces after the equal sign.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Well, there is still the regular expression problem. If the function were `myfunction <- function(...) cat("Mean = 3925")` it would still pass the test.

Comment: Of course! MrFlick is absolutely correct! I edited my answer (again ;)

Comment: If you remove the trailing space in the origianl function, the `fixed=TRUE` is not needed. Please correct. (The problem arose because the default `sep` arg for `cat` is `" "`

Comment: I did "try it for myself". I think this is an X/Y problem. I suppose your final edit does clarify the lack of stringency of the original argument to `prints_text`.